# WPF application works fine on my pc but not in the client PC

Tags: wpf, deployment, web-scraping

I have created a WPF application (web scraper), the debug version works as expected on my pc but after copying the files to the clients it shows the User interface and after pressing the button to scrap it doesn't do anything, I  am having the same OS as the client (Windows 7 64 bit), I can't guess what the problem is ? can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are you checking the client's role compared to yours?

Comment: i don't know what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alongside any other diagnostics you are doing to investigate why you can run an app on your machine, but a client cannot run it on his machine is to double check the roles you are both in...

> As a developer, you most likely run your development computer with
>   Full Trust permissions. Therefore, you do not see the same security
>   exceptions when you debug the application that users may see when they
>   run it with restricted permissions.
>
> In order to catch these exceptions, you have to debug the application
>   with the same permissions as the end user. Debugging with restricted
>   permissions can be enabled on the Security page of the Project
>   Designer.
>
> When you debug an application with restricted permissions, exceptions
>   will be raised for any code security demands that have not been
>   enabled on the Security page. An exception helper will appear,
>   providing suggestions about how to modify your code to prevent the
>   exception.

[Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z17ceyya%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

Here is a snippet to pop up all the various roles...

```
        WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetAnonymous();
        WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(wi);
        foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof (WindowsBuiltInRole)))
        {
            if (wp.IsInRole(e.ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} is in role {1}", wp.Identity.Name, e.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} is NOT in role {1}", wp.Identity.Name, e.ToString()));
            }
        }
```

These things will help you further investigate why the same program behaves differently on two computers driven by two different people.

Comment: thank you, but the problem is not about this, it's about the .net framework version installed in the client PC

Comment: run the program called CLRVer.exe on both machines